# Inject HTML in webform page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

how can i inject HTML tags in runtime on ASPX pages
below code is not show in the client page as below PS
but, it shows in chrome inspect page only
[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string HTML = @"<table><tr>
                        <td valign='top'>
                            <asp:Label ID='LB900' runat='server' CssClass='aspLabelRequired' Text='<%$ Resources:Resource,Bundle %>'/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID='TB900' runat='server' CssClass='aspTextbox' MaxLength='150' Width='171px'></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID='RV900' runat='server' ControlToValidate='TB900' CssClass='aspError' Display='Dynamic' ErrorMessage='*Required' ValidationGroup='RequestValidation'></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr></table>";


        div1.InnerHtml = HTML;
   }
}
```

Comment: it converts TextBox TextBox = new TextBox(); to input tag

Comment: You have to add the ASP controls as controls, not as the text that represents the controls. That is because of the way that it is processed into HTML entities and onclick handlers etc. are added.

Comment: You must set runat attribute for your control then access to that from code-behind
`
<div runat="server" id="div1">
</div>
`

Comment: I did that still not work

Comment: Andrew please explain more

Answer (score 0):

When you are using string to create your HTML, you need to use HTML Tags only.
Because your HTML is in string variable, .Net Framework won't be able to determine that it is a server control. It will just set whatever defined in your string in the DIV tag.

If you want to use ASP controls only (<asp:...>), better to use them in ASPX pages rather than the code behind. This way, .Net Framework will automatically convert them to relevant HTML controls during runtime.

Also, if you set the **runat="server"** attribute in your ASP controls, you will be able to manipulate them from the code behind too.

Comment: thank you so much, i guess there is no solution for my case